# Having problems using the Android Tools Project Build System

Tags: android, gradle

So I've been trying to automate an Android build using http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.

It's still very unclear to me how to exactly use the build system, so if anyone has experience with this or Gradle in general might be able to answer the following questions for me.

Using this build file as a reference.

```
//
// A basic Android application that follows all the conventions
//
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    target = "android-15"
    testBuildType = "debug"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode = 12
        versionName = "2.0"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        targetSdkVersion = 16

        signingStoreLocation = "debug.keystore"
        signingStorePassword = "android"
        signingKeyAlias = "androiddebugkey"
        signingKeyPassword = "android"

        buildConfig "private final static boolean DEFAULT = true;", \
                    "private final static String FOO = \"foo\";"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            packageNameSuffix = ".debug"

            buildConfig "private final static boolean DEBUG2 = false;"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {

       main {}
       test {}
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress "txt"
    }
}
```

1. How exactly do you add dependencies to this for building? Using Gradle's dependencies is throwing a build error for me.
2. How would you create different build environments? And then run these from the command line?
3. What's the point of sourceSets outside of main and test?

Thanks for the help, and any general guides in addition to the questions above answered would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Also, if someone else might suggest a completely different build system for Android, with the expectation that it has an easy and quick learning curve, it'd be great.

Comment: Ant dosen't really have build in dependency management or automated testing. Would like this baked into the framework.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not sure you can have empty blocks to configure sourceSets.main and sourceSets.test. If you are using the default folder structure (src/main/java and src/test/java), I'd remove those and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

1- dependencies is added the regular gradle way, so for instance:

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r7'
}

More info: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

2- Not sure what you mean. If you mean different build variants, you'll have to create product flavors (see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/using-the-new-build-system).

building from the command line, you just run "gradle assemble". see doc above.

3- SourceSets is to configure the sourcesets of the default config (main/test), the flavors, and the build types. Unlike a Java gradle build you can't just add new sourcesets and have them be compiled automatically.
This is why this is in the android namespace (android.sourcesets) instead of at the top level like the sourceSets object provided by the default Java plugin.

Comment: I've currently shelved using the tool so far and am exploring using the android maven plugin as I'm finding the guides super lacking. Coming from a non-operations background, and using Eclipse or Intellij to build my Android app, I've found this just too difficult too understand right now.